# How to put < -> negative sign and a number and letter in one cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to reference a cell in my formula and the formula will accept values of number and "D" for days, "Y" for year, "W" weeks and so on. So for example I want to retrive data for 5 yers so should be "5Y". I also need to add a negative sign before so "-5Y".

I want to reference the cell so that if the user inputs 5Y the formula will automatically reference "-5Y"

Comment: Does `=“-“&A1` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this formula?

```
=NUMBERVALUE("-"&B2)
```

[image]